# What are the Best Methods for Creating Pulsed DC or AC Current at 2.4 - 2.5 GHz Frequency Range?

Tags: high-voltage, high-frequency, high-current

Some of you may be aware that UFOs are sometimes recorded emitting microwave radiation. I think they might be using an electromagnetic coil that is being pulsed with DC current or is using AC current oscillating at a rate that corresponds to microwave radiation frequencies.

I want to build a coil and mess around with it in that frequency range with an applied power of around 1 kW. What would be the best methods for generating such high frequency pulsed DC or AC current?

In my research so far I have come up with charging a capacitor and discharging it repeatedly into the electromagnetic coil as the capacitor discharge provides a high current pulse which will create a strong electromagnetic field. Since cheaper transistors are limited to around 1.2kV I was thinking a 1kV capacitor should be used. Commercially available power supplies for a 1kV 1kW output are expensive.

I was thinking of creating a single stage Marx generator controlled by a IGBT, MOSFET, or possibly an off the shelf ZVS driver made for powering flybacks with a pulsed current, use that to create pulsed DC which would be fed into a Cockcroft Walton generator to create higher voltage DC of around 1kV, then run that into a single stage Marx generator to charge and rapidly discharge the 1kV capacitor through a MOSFET.

I am having trouble finding a 1kV, 1A, 1kW, RF MOSFET or other very high frequency MOSFET.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If something is unidentified how can we be sure it's emitting anything?

Comment: *Some of you may be aware that UFOs are sometimes recorded emitting microwave radiation.* UFOs emitting in the polluted ISM band just means whoever controls them is pretty damn stupid is all I've got to say.

Comment: I don't know if you have much regard for safety, but, "Studies reveal that the exposure to cell phones, microwave ovens, laptops, or Wi-Fi produces deleterious effects on the testes, which may affect sperm count, morphology, motility, an increased DNA damage, causing micronuclei formation and genomic instability, as well as disruptions in protein kinases, hormones and ..." https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22897403/%23

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is a microwave oven. Those use the exact frequency and power range that you described (some a bit less, some a bit more). They essentially contain a radio transmitter (magnetron) that fills the cooking chamber with so much radio frequency power that whatever is in there gets cooked.

**Please don't experiment with powerful radio frequency transmitters like microwave magnetrons.** They can cook you just as easily as they cook food in a microwave, and there's also the extreme danger of the required high voltage power supply.

If you still want to experiment while taking slightly less risk, you can put your experiment into a literal microwave oven. It'll have the same effect, but you're protected by the closed cooking chamber, which prevents radio frequency energy from escaping and hurting you. Of course, whatever you put in there will still get cooked, and most electronics will malfunction instantly. There's also the risk of toxic gases being released as your experiment inevitably catches on fire, plus likely a whole bunch of other weird and wonderful risks that you'll have to evaluate. This is still really unsafe, but less so than an open microwave transmitter.

Comment: Microwave ovens do not use high frequency AC or pulsed DC to power an electromagnetic coil which is the primary focus of the experiment. As a result a magnetron cannot be used.

Comment: @RobertFrancisJr You cannot use a coil at GHz frequencies because the wavelength of the signal (about 12cm) is too short. The total length of wire in the coil would need to be smaller than about lambda/10, which is 1.2cm. If you try to make a coil with 3 turns using that, it'd only be about 1mm in diameter.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, building such a powerful, unlicensed transmitter runs afoul of regulatory agency restrictions.

Second, designing for such high power levels is, well, quite dangerous, even for qualified people. **We're not just talking run-of-the mill electric shock danger, but seriously hurt- or unalive-you levels of danger.**

That said, what you describe - making high-power pulsed 2.4GHz RF - is exactly what a microwave oven does, which uses a high-voltage transformer and a Magnetron tube. [Studying these will give you an idea of what's involved](https://hackaday.com/2019/12/05/a-magnetron-tear-down/), and **hopefully guide you away from taking on such a dangerous project.**

Comment: I understand how magnetrons work which is why I am not using one. The important part is a coil that oscillates at those frequencies. It is my hope that the torque created by a pulsed DC or AC current in the coil will orient electric dipoles within range of the coil, like hydrogen for example, parallel with the field lines of the coil. Creating any microwaves would just be incidental.

Comment: High-power radiative work in microwave frequencies typically uses waveguides, not coils. A Magnetron has an oscillating cavity where it self-generates a microwave energy (e.g., 2.4GHz) at its resonant frequency. Its output is fed to a waveguide, where it could be used to power a RADAR or cook your mac'n'cheese.

Comment: A pulsed radar may be closer to what you're looking for. radartutorial.eu/02.basics/Pulse%20Radar.en.html But again, waveguide, not coil. Indeed, pulsing the power to a magnetron on and off will make a pulsed RF.